# Keep full screen while switching to other app?

Tags: youtube, full-screen

I want to make a YouTube video that I put in my second screen stay maximized while I go and do something in another window on my primary monitor.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just a suggestion since I do not have a dual monitor setup... have you tried using the HTML5 version of the youtube video? This will take up the fullscreen of the browser window and not the monitor.

Comment: @phwd: it looks like the video i want does not support HTML5. :/

Comment: Which video a VEVO video ? Those would not work. For everything else you can use youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID

Comment: @phwd: that last thing you told me is just what i need, so if you promote it to an answer i can accept it. :)

Comment: done :D Glad to help out

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For everything other than VEVO (and certain copyright videos) you can use `youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID` this should bring it to 100% browser view area.

Comment: That, in combination with chrome presentation mode, is pretty nice.

Answer (score 4):

This is something that flash decides locally, not some setting on Youtube.

If you run windows [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5419028/keep-flash-videos-in-full-screen-on-dual-monitors) over on Lifehacker tells you where to download a modified dll that will allow flash to remain full screen when it does not have focus.

Another option might be to use a html5 able browser (Chrome, Safari for example) and tell Youtube to use that to play video. According to [this page](http://www.youtube.com/html5) *Full-screen support is partially implemented*

The [same page](http://www.youtube.com/html5) also has a link to lets you join the html5 beta program.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without needing to install an old and potentially vulnerable version of Flash?

Comment: @RCIX - See edit

Answer (score 3):

I use VLC for that. It can even load playlists (might need some extra scripts for that to work). Also it skips advertisments.

Just press ctrl+n and enter youtube url.

also:
https://superuser.com/questions/351612/how-to-watch-youtube-fullscreen-on-one-monitor-of-a-dual-monitor-display

Comment: Is that a web application? I guess not....

Comment: The original question doesn't seem to be web application related either, this is why I added a link to the more or less same question elsewhere.
Google brought me here with the same question and I added a (in my opinion) better alternative. That is all.

Comment: I guess you're right....

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install Flash Keep FullScreen from this website :
http://flash-full-screen-multiple-monitor.clangen.com/

It will keep full screen for the video, even if they are paused or finished.
It will also work for other applications in fullscreen, like Flash games on Facebook.

Very easy to use and install.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

## [Youtube Leanback](http://youtube.com/leanback)

I was looking after the same problem and found an awesome solution that works for all videos (VEVO as well).

Sign in to leanback, and it will give you a device code, which you can authorise by visiting `http://google.com/device`. After the authorization is successful, you can browse all your videos in full screen.

Also, signing in is optional, and you can browse through videos normally.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Firefox 13 and later:
type `about:config` in the address bar to go to the Firefox configuration settings.
Paste `full-screen-api.exit-on-deactivate` into the search bar and double click the resulting option to change it's value to false.